# How to get fonts loading cross domain in Firefox

Tags: css, apache, fonts, cdn

I'm using limelight CDN for static files. I get the error in native firefox inspector:

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "nimbus-bold" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://cdn-store.example.com/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'nimbus-bold';
src: url('/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.eot%3F%23iefix') format("embedded-opentype");
src: url('/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff') format("woff");
src: url('/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.ttf') format("truetype");
src: url('/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.svg%23nimbus_sans_p_otbold') format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I tried the following, but it did not help:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

-bash-4.1$ curl -I http://cdn-store.example.com/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 16:58:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:45:31 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 24040
Connection: keep-alive

-bash-4.1$ curl -I http://store.example.com/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 17:04:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:45:31 GMT
ETag: "146124-5de8-4f24b944b4eff"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 24040
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

EDIT:
with 'AddType' directive I get the following results, however the fonts don't load

```
$ curl -I http://store.example.com/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 15:09:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:45:31 GMT
ETag: "146124-5de8-4f24b944b4eff"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 24040
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-font-woff

$ curl -I http://cdn-store.example.com/fonts/nimbussanspot-bold-webfont.woff
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Oracle)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/x-font-woff
Age: 55
Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 15:08:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:45:31 GMT
Content-Length: 24040
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 2):

Your webfont files are served in `text/plain` Content-Type instead of the proper one such as `application/x-font-woff`.

Try something like this in your apache config file see if it helps:

```
<Location /webfont>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
   AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
   AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
</Location>
```

Comment: curl outputs Content-Type: application/x-font-ttf and font loads without a problem. However, I still see error message in the console 'cross-site access not allowed'. Should I ignore it?

Comment: I suspect this warning message may come from some other assets you are trying to load from the page, otherwise the font won't show correctly.

Comment: I was mistaken, the fonts do not load. Can you suggest another solution?

Answer (score 2):

On your server you will need to add: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for fonts.
At `.htaccess` add:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```